# Positional audio triggering (HTML, CSS, skrollr, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, skrollr

I am making a digital storytelling which is a website containing images and audio tracks. I came across skrollr today and found it interesting. Now I am wondering if anybody knows a solution to using skrollr with audio tracks - so that the audio will stop and start based on the scroll-position. I appreciate all ideas and creative thoughts.

Link to skrollr: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Comment: Cool idea, but you're more likely to get advice if you post something you've tried yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skrollr only animates changes in CSS. You'll need to use javascript to do what you want.

This is easy enough to do with jQuery. Set an event handler to watch for scroll events, then check if the document is scrolled within particular bounds, then do whatever you want (e.g. play/pause audio). There are a million solutions for playing audio. I'd recommend howler.js.

Comment: Thank you! I found a solution with Howler, "window.onscroll()" to check for movement and "document.body.scrollTop" to find placing on page. Not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it but it seems to be working well =)

Comment: That's pretty much how I would do it. There might be a better solution, but it sounds like you've already figured it out well enough.